# Create a variable path using glob.glob and os.path.join in python

Tags: python, glob, os.path

I am using Python 3.6 and would like to know how to create a variable path to locate a file based on a year folder that changes. I have the following file path:

```
C:\Users\al123\Desktop\scripts_test\tutorials\2021\Conference\Notes\single notes\Conference notes content.txt
```

This code gives me the correct files with the word "notes" in the name:

```
for name in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\al123\Desktop\scripts_test\tutorials\2021\**\*notes*.txt',recursive=True):
    print(name)
```

However, there is a 2021 folder and a 2022 folder, and I want it to change dynamically based on today's date. I will have a variable `b` that gives me the year based on today's date. Assuming that the path before the year folder is the same, when I try to add the variable b for the year using `os.path.join` it gives me nothing:

```
a=r'C:\Users\al123\Desktop\scripts_test\tutorials'
b=(date.today()-timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y')
c=r'**\*notes*.txt'
for name in glob.glob(os.path.join(a,b,c)):
    print(name)
```

What do I need to change in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slightly different approach, but you could turn this into a `lambda` expression:

```py
plain_path = r'C:\Users\al123\Desktop\scripts_test\tutorials\{year}\**\*notes*.txt'
variable_path = lambda year: plain_path.format(year=year)

print(variable_path(2001))
# C:\Users\al123\Desktop\scripts_test\tutorials\2001\**\*notes*.txt

print(variable_path(2002))
# C:\Users\al123\Desktop\scripts_test\tutorials\2002\**\*notes*.txt
```

Comment: this is a much more elegant approach compared to what I was trying to do. It works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `recursive=True` keyword argument:

```py
for name in glob.glob(os.path.join(a,b,c), recursive=True):
    print(name)
```